# Why are saturation and color very different when I open my JPEG photos in different programs?

Tags: color, color-management

I just noticed that my photos are displayed all "greyed" when I open them in some software, but appear correctly in other.
For example Firefox or paint.net display the wrong colors, but with the photos tool from windows or Internet Explorer it is OK:

[image: example]

What is going on here and how can I fix this ?

Here is the link to the original photo : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5D8_5xfiMhqU1VsQ3ZZWUhqMTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is probably a color profile problem, but it would help if you linked to a photo for us to test it.

Comment: Start by telling us the image file format you're using, what version of Firefox, what version of WIndows OS and what the actual "photo tool" applications are.

Comment: File format is jpg. Windows 10, lastest version of firefox. By "photo tool" I mean the default app to open photos in Windows 10. I send the photo to my Android phone and to my work computer (windows 7) and I had the same problem.

Comment: I have added a link to the original photo in the question

Comment: The image on the right looks much better than the one on the left. it looks like an incorrect color profile was used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This image has an input device color profile attached, `OlympusStylus1-Generic`. The highly-saturated and vivid images are from applications which are correctly loading and applying this profile. The more subdued images are ignoring the profile and interpreting the data as sRGB, leading to color shifts.

For what it's worth, while the non-profile image is clearly not correct, the profile itself results in higher saturation than is realistic.

It looks like you converted or edited the image with Capture One. Phase One [recommends](https://help.phaseone.com/en/CO8/Output/File-formats/Colors-in-Capture-One.aspx) that for web use, images be converted to sRGB. (I think for most people who are not spending a lot of time with color profiling and management that this is in fact the best choice for *all* use.) Make sure you export your images in that color space. That page also notes the menu item `ICC Profile>Embed Camera profile` — I suggest turning that *off*, because as you've noticed, not all software honors that. Just make the output sRGB and move on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to fix this on hundreds of image at once so that they all look the same whatever the applications ?

Comment: Do you have the originals in Capture One still? If not, you could use ImageMagick; there's an explanation of [applying and then removing ICC profiles here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633390/apply-and-remove-color-profile-with-image-magick).